# SQL Server Calculate Number of date in a Year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I extract the number of days in a year base on a field in SQL?

For example: I have a Date field in SQL Server

```
Date
1/4/2015
2/1/2015
2/21/205
```

I want to use that date field to get me the day out of 365 so the result would look like this

```
Day of 365  Date
4   1/4/2015
32  2/1/2015
52  2/21/205
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

very useful [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420(v=sql.100).aspx) function has overload for day, week, day of week, day of year, quater and others

```
select DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, [DATE]) as DayOfYear,  [DATE]
```

DayOfYear can be 366 in case of leap year (e.g. 31 December of 2000)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`DATEPART()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

```
SELECT DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR , '1/4/2015')
```